# Getting data with React and Spring pagination

Tags: reactjs, spring, pagination, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring data Pagination with React to get some data. I have two ways of getting the data from the backend, the first one when the component re-render. The second way when clicking on a button.

```js
const searchButton = () => {
  isLoading(true);
  searchOrder(searchInput, pageNumber, 'name').then((res) => {
    setOrders(res.data.content);
    setTotalElements(res.data.totalElements);
    setCurrentPage(res.data.number);
    setItemsCountPerPage(res.data.size);
    isLoading(false);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  isLoading(true);
  getOrders(pageNumber, 'name').then((res) => {
    setOrders(res.data.content);
    setTotalElements(res.data.totalElements);
    setCurrentPage(res.data.number);
    setItemsCountPerPage(res.data.size);
    isLoading(false);
  });
}, [pageNumber, refreshPage]);
```

When clicking on the button I will get the data, but when trying to go to the next page, it will fire the useEffect and will get the data from it. My question: how should I go to the next page from the data that I got when clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the content of the search button in the useEffect method as a conditional statement.